# Django 1.7 refactor into model inheritance

Tags: django

Just had a look through these ones:

[South migration for multi-table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611427/south-migration-for-multi-table-inheritance)

and

[Using south to refactor a Django model with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600129/using-south-to-refactor-a-django-model-with-inheritance)

Both were based on deprecated 'south' application. Has anyone tried using django 1.7+ migrations successfully to refactor models to have inheritance?

Eg. From:

```
class OrderItem(TimeStampedMixin, models.Model):
    ...
```

To:

```
class BaseOrderItem(models.Model):
    pass

class OrderItem(TimeStampedMixin, BaseOrderItem):
    ...
```

When I run `makemigration orders`, the magic didn't happen to backfill the base model:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'baseorderitem_ptr' to orderitem without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

This seems like a mission to accomplish.